# How to pull distinct rows based on combination of few columns of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, distinct

Pardon the question title but I have table CUSTOMER(ACCT_NUM,LRN,NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,COUNTRY)

I have to write a query to pull records which have more than 1 (distinct) combination of name,address,city,state and country for a **same combination of acct_num and LRN**.
This is what I have tried but I am not sure if it is correct. 
I just want to group by acct_num and LRN but I know group by wont allow me to exclude other columns.

```
select distinct name, address, state, country, city, 
COUNT(1) from CUSTOMER 
group by acct_num,
 LRN ,
 name,
 address,
 state, 
 country, 
 city
 having COUNT(1) > 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating some test data

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE
(
    ACCT_NUM INT,
    LRN INT,
    name varchar(20),
    address varchar(100),
    state varchar(2),
    country varchar(100),
    city varchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Customer
VALUES
( 1, 1, 'Test1', 'Addr1', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 1, 1, 'Test1', 'Addr2', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 1, 1, 'Test1', 'Addr3', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 1, 1, 'Test1', 'Addr4', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 2, 1, 'Test2', 'Addr1', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 2, 1, 'Test2', 'Addr1', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' ),
( 3, 1, 'Test3', 'Addr1', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' )
```

I use rank to figure out all of the distinct combinations (if they are equal, rank would be equal as well)

```
 SELECT * FROM
 (
    SELECT *, 
        Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ACCT_NUM, c.LRN ORDER BY c.Name, c.Address, c.State, c.Country, c.City) RK
    FROM @Customer c
) d
WHERE d.RK > 1
```

Output:

```
ACCT_NUM    LRN name    address state   country city    RK
1   1   Test1   Addr2   FL  USA Tampa   2
1   1   Test1   Addr3   FL  USA Tampa   3
1   1   Test1   Addr4   FL  USA Tampa   4
```

Comment: What a wonderful answer @Kevin! Just one question, what if in your above result-set, I want to include one additional row 1, 1, 'Test1', 'Addr1', 'FL', 'USA', 'Tampa' too. How to do that? If I remove the d.RK > 1 condition, it will return all rows.

Comment: you could use the output and join against the main table using acct_num, lrn and then get all the rows for the acct.

Answer (score 2):

The `RANK() OVER` answer is correct but does fail to show the first address in the results.

I would prefer to use an additional level of nesting to accomplish this.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY acct_num, LRN) AS distinct_matches
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      acct_num, LRN, name, address, state, country, city
    FROM
      CUSTOMER
    GROUP BY
      acct_num, LRN, name, address, state, country, city
  )
    AS unique_rows
)
  AS counted_unique_rows
WHERE
  distinct_matches > 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatBailie. You are right, the above answer is correct and your answer includes that one missing row too. I am in a fix which answer to accept :( Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @ReeyaOberoi - Whichever answer you found most helpful to you.  In other words, whichever you like :)

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way.

Here's a [link to SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17c99/1) borrowing the example dataset from Kevin's answer so you can see the results.

Get list of distinct customers. From this list group on acct_num and lrn. Any having a count > 1 means there's more than 1 combination when taking into account the rest of the fields. Now pull it from customer where it exists from the previous query to get all the data.

```
select distinct * from customer c
where exists
  (
    select acct_num, lrn
    from
      (
        select distinct * from customer
       ) base
    where c.acct_num = base.acct_num and c.lrn = base.lrn
    group by acct_num, lrn
    having count(1) > 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct name, address, state, country, city, acct_num
FROM (
    SELECT  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, address, state, country, city) AS RN
    FROM CUSTOMER 
    group by acct_num,
             LRN ,
             name,
             address,
             state, 
             country, 
             city) AS n
WHERE RN > 1
```

May be this works!!!as per my assumption.

Comment: This is the reverse of what the OP requested.  This returns the `acct_num, LRN` combinations that share the same `name, address, state, country, city` with at least one other `acct_num, LRN`.

Comment: @mohan111 - thanks for helping but I feel you have missed to include name, address, state, country, city in your inner query and even if I add it, I feel that it may yield similar results to what I have tried, although in a bit more complicated way.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the acct_num & LRN combinations with more than one distinct combination of the other fields.  If you want to see all of the other information that is different, it sort of defeats the purpose of aggregates IMO.

```
select acct_num, LRN, COUNT(*)
from CUSTOMER
group by acct_num, LRN
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Only if there is a unique constraint put against all of the fields.  What if one `acct_num, LRN` combination has the *exact same* `name, address, city, state, country` on multiple rows?